# How to Dump data from temp table to original table using @@spid

Tags: sql-server

I have a temp table let say `Temp_Table1_77` in my `tempdb`,in this the last numeric number is my session id(`@@spid`) ,and this temp table have some values on it. Now I want to dump that temp table data to my database table,let say that database is `MYDATA` and table name is `table1`.
I don't know how to dump that temp data to original database table based on spid .

Comment: You're creating "temp" tables that are actually normal tables with the @@spid number in them? Why aren't you just using #TempTable that would be separate for each spid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your table local(#) or global(##) temporary table?

Use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` syntax to copy data:

```
INSERT INTO MYDATA.dbo.table1(cols, ...)
SELECT cols, ...
FROM #Temp_Table1_77
WHERE <your_column_with_session_id> = <SPID_value>;
```

Comment: thanks for your response sir,but session_id is not a known keyword in my sql server 2008,can i use @@spid in the place of session_id?\

Comment: @SaurabhKumar `session_id` is column where you store @SPID, In your question is `last numeric number is my session id(@@spid)`. Change to your name

Comment: sir i do use sql server 2008 R2 ,but session_id is not a known keyword,so can i use @@spid in the place of session_id in the following sql block?